# Any way to restore connect to windows share as a different user?

Tags: networking, samba

When I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 the file manager lost the ability to connect to windows shares as a specific user(from 'connect to server') from the file manager.  I could be connected to z share as one user and x share as another, but now connect to server offers no place to add credentials as it used to. When I try without credentials, I get an error that says "UNABLE TO ACCESS LOCATION - FAILED TO MOUNT WINDOWS SHARE - PERMISSION DENIED". I find screenshots where it's supposed to prompt me for a username and password, But I never get it. Just an error. Is there something that maybe carried over from the previous version? Should I delete ~/.nautilus? or something?

Comment: I moved every .* file to a temp directory and rebooted my system and logged in. It still does not prompt me for anything when trying to access a share. Just an error. So my profile is probably not the issue.

Comment: If you are unsure of it being a profile related issue or not; the first step to take here is to create a new user and try Connect to Server. Do you still not receive the prompt under a new user?

Comment: Is it needed that you can input the username/password on a per-share level? Maybe it would be enough to connect to one (or more) servers with always the same shares and credentials?

Answer (score 8):

If you open up your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file you should see at the bottom the share definition. Generically it looks something like this:

```
[share-name]
comment = 
path = /media/[some-name]
read only = No
guest ok = yes
```

What you want to do is add a "force user" line to that share definition so that the remote user appears to be you:

```
[share-name]
comment = 
path = /media/[some-name]
read only = No
force user = [your-user-name]
guest ok = yes
```

Then restart samba:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Official sources: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#FORCEUSER

Answer (score 1):

I think that developers have decided to simplify the way "Connect to server" work.
With most servers, you should be asked to enter your credentials when you try to access a share... But with some others, you first have to explicitly specify which user you want to use. In fact, in that case, you simply have to use a syntax similar to the one you would use under Windows.

Basic syntax to use in "Connect to server" :

```
smb://UserNameToUseToConnect@SMBServerName/ShareName/
```

Example :

```
smb://franck@myserver/myshare/
```

Using this syntax, one window letting you enter your domain name and password will appear.

I hope that this will help you to solve your problem. If you still can't provide your domain name and password (no window/error message appears) or else, more information about the configuration of your server might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This probably shouldn't be an answer because it's a bit speculative, but perhaps the lack of a prompt is another feature removal in the 3.6 version of Nautilus. It might be fairly painless to try installing the 3.4 version from the SoluOS, as regards [this article](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/get-nautilus-34-features-back-in-ubuntu.html) from WebUpd8.

Basically :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/experiments
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
killall nautilus
```

Good luck!

To roll back this change :

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/experiments
killall nautilus
```